# Registering mouse gestures in VLC (building an extension)

Tags: lua, vlc

I'm working on an extension for VLC (VideoLAN player) using Lua. Can anyone give me a hint as to how to listen for/register mouse gestures which take place in the main VLC window?

(Specifically, I'd like to record the locations of clicks and drags on the main viewing window.)

If it can only be done in C and in the main project, still, any insight would be of value, as the documentation on the project is wanting.

Comment: Have you seen [this documentation](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/)?

Comment: Yes, I have. However, I have not been able to extract the answer to my question from it, and I didn't believe that any of the objects in the README offered this capability. Can you point me more specifically?

Comment: actually I don't see a way to do it, either in that file or any of the "linked" READMEs (under [here](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/)).